# Use background-position behavior with img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to get the `background-position:"center"` behavior on my `<img>` tags.

Here is the work : http://ns366377.ovh.net/siow/perso/kuala/

Basically, I would like my first content block (picture diaporama) to have the same behavior as my last content block (a picture of a plane).

Behavior in question :

- The block has a certain height (for the plane block it's 600px and for the first content block it's `$(window).height();`)
- On resize, the picture stays at the user's maximum browser width capaticy. In other words, the user would be able to see only part of the picture (the middle in this case). The pictures do not change width.

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm get you right, you want to center the images in your slider.
If your images in the 'first block' have the same width (1366px) you can add this.

HTML:

```
<img src="somePic.png" alt="" id="1" class="fade images" style="height: 572px; width: 1366px;">
```

CSS:

```
.images {
 margin-left: calc(50% - 683px);
}
```

But if you have pictures with different width you can use JavaScript or even jQuery. Here jQuery solution.

jQuery:

```
var getWidthOfImage = $('.images').css('width');
var calcLeft = getWidthOfImage/2;
$('.images').css('left', 'calc(50% - ' + calcLeft + ')');
```

**EDIT:**

So I read the question again and you said that the width of the image will resize dependent to the width of the browser. So if you do this you dont need to center it. Your 'last content block' at the end will not resize and thats why it looks better. I advise you to take the sesize-function out. If you want to center it. And no normal user will resize the window.

Comment: Thanks, although is not exactly what i was looking for, I got a better understanding of centering elements. Cheers mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<img />` a fixed width, an absolute position and place the left-hand margin of the `<img />` in the middle of the `<img />`:

**CSS:**

```
img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
width: 1366px;
margin-left: -683px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 you can use `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain` 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp